# Magento : How to get value of checkbox in observer?

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, newsletter

I want to add a checkbox after Place order button. So , If someone checked the checkbox then he/she should subscribe. I have added checkbox in button.phtml page and I have written observer('checkout_submit_all_after') also but I am not getting value of checkbox. Please help me in this.

[image]

Comment: try Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('YOUR_CHECK_NAME').

Comment: @GopalPatel : It's not working. I am getting null value

Comment: Provide code of this checkbox. means how exactly you have added that checkbox

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" 
  title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1"  checked="checked" class="checkbox" />

Comment: this is my code in frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/button.phtml

Comment: try to put checkbox under /home/osp67/www/aws/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml and get the value by Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('YOUR_CHECK_NAME')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58774/discussion-between-borncoder-and-gopal-patel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable `terms and condition` on checkout page from admin and add your checkbox code in `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml`

After `<form>` add your checkbox code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1"  checked="checked" class="checkbox" /> I would like to receive the latest offers and discounts.
```

Create a custom module with this below code in `config.xml` file.

```
<global>
    <events>
        <checkout_submit_all_after>
            <observers>
                <wildnet_latestnews_model_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Wildnet_Latestnews_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>updateNewsletter</method>
                </wildnet_latestnews_model_observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_submit_all_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

Create function in Observer.php File:

```
    public function updateNewsletter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
    {
        //get value from Form
        $isSubscribe = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('is_subscribed');  
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $order = $event->getOrder();

        if ($isSubscribe == 1){
            $status = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($order->getCustomerEmail());
        }
    }
```