# Magento2 : How to get value of checkbox in observer?

Tags: magento2, php, php-7

I will refer to previous post: [Magento : How to get value of checkbox in observer?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174420/magento-how-to-get-value-of-checkbox-in-observer/251351#251351)

Anyone have example of how to do the exact same for Magento 2?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166917/get-post-data-in-checkout-success-observer

Comment: Thanks, i've already tried this before asking the question. I'm not getting any results this way.
I have tried with following events:
checkout_submit_all_after,
sales_model_service_quote_submit_success

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get post data, in Checkout success observer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166917/get-post-data-in-checkout-success-observer)